# deploying Facebook messenger chatBot with python gnewsclient error

Tags: python-3.x

I have been deploying Facebook messenger chatBot  I followed all steps even installing python libary  gnewsclient when is about to use some gnewsclient commend  I got syntax invalid see the picture below can some one help me please i made tree day trying to do that
[invalid syentax](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJRv7.png)

Answer (score 0):

the gnewsclient api is currently broken. I hope it will be fixed in a few days. Better wait for the fix or use google search api for the news.